# how to iterate json response value from server in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

hii i'm new to javascript i have an web request and its give response as JSON format, the task is that i need to parse the data into array

**here is my sample reponse :**

```
"Employee" : {
  "Employee_Names" : [
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "anand",
        "Name" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : "Ln",

     },
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "av",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : "FiLi",

     },
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "books",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : "Ln",

     },
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "kanagalu",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : null,

     },
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "specialty-av",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : "Fn-Ln",

     }
  ],
  "FOUND_Name" : [ null ],
  "OTHER_Name" : [
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "kindle-cs-support",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : null,

     },
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "noreply-ops-jobs",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : null,

     }
  ],
  "PERSONAL_Name" : [ null ],
  "PROJECTED_Name" : [
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "anand.venkatesan",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : "Fn.Ln",

     },
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "anandv",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : "FnLi",

     },
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "vanand",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : "LiFn",

     }
  ]
  },
```

what i need is i need from **Employee_Names** object i want all Name in one array similarly From **OTHER_Name** i want all Name to be stored in array

i dono how to parse the data with dynamic Array size

Comment: You should never do somethig like `"PERSONAL_Name" : [ null ]` do instead `"PERSONAL_Name" : []`

Comment: show how should look the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**Array map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to get all the particular property values from an array of object into a single array.

**To fetch all the names into an single array from Employee_Names :**

```
  var empNames = employee.Employee_Names.map(function(item) {
    return item.Name;
  });
```

**To fetch all the names into an single array from OTHER_Name :**

```
  var otherNames = employee.OTHER_Name.map(function(item) {
    return item.Name;
  });
```

**Working Demo**

```js
var employee = {
  "Employee_Names" : [
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "anand",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : "Ln",

     },
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "av",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : "FiLi",

     },
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "books",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : "Ln",

     },
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "kanagalu",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : null,

     },
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "specialty-av",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : "Fn-Ln",

     }
  ],
  "FOUND_Name" : [ null ],
  "OTHER_Name" : [
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "kindle-cs-support",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : null,

     },
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "noreply-ops-jobs",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : null,

     }
  ]
  };
  
  var empNames = employee.Employee_Names.map(function(item) {
    return item.Name;
  });
  
  var otherNames = employee.OTHER_Name.map(function(item) {
    return item.Name;
  });  
  
  console.log("Employee Names", empNames);
  console.log("Other Names", otherNames);
```

Answer (score 2):

To get all values in the field "name" from the Employee.Employee_Names array

```
var resultArray = Employee.Employee_Names.map(function(a) {return a.Name;});
```

resultArray will then be 
`["anand", "av", "books", "kanagalu", "specialty-av"`]

Comment: @Krishna9960 as map being part of ES6 you can optimize it even more with fat arrow function, see my answer.

Comment: @loelsonk : Agreed.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, this should suit your needs.

We loop through `"Employee_Names"` objects.

```
// ES6 code    
var allNames = employee["Employee_Names"].map(bar => bar.Name);

// pure javascript
var allNames = [];
for (i = 0; i < employee["Employee_Names"].length; i++) {
  var element = employee["Employee_Names"][i];

  // We push only name
  allNames.push( element.Name );

  // We push full json object
   //allNames.push( element );
}
```

Now we assign new json key with our `allNames` array.

```
employee = Object.assign(employee, { "NEW_NAMES" : allNames });
```

Check working exmaple:

```js
var employee = {
  "Employee_Names" : [
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "anand",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : "Ln",

     },
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "av",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : "FiLi",

     },
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "books",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : "Ln",

     },
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "kanagalu",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : null,

     },
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "specialty-av",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : "Fn-Ln",

     }
  ],
  "FOUND_Name" : [ ],
  "OTHER_Name" : [
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "kindle-cs-support",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : null,

     },
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "noreply-ops-jobs",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : null,

     }
  ],
  "PERSONAL_Name" : [  ],
  "PROJECTED_Name" : [
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "anand.venkatesan",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : "Fn.Ln",

     },
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "anandv",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : "FnLi",

     },
     {
        "BAR_RATING" : "0",
        "Name" : "vanand",
        "Name_RATING" : "0",
        "PATTERN" : "LiFn",

     }
  ]
  };


// ES6
//var allNames = employee["Employee_Names"].map(bar => bar.Name);

// pure javascript
var allNames = [];
for (i = 0; i < employee["Employee_Names"].length; i++) {
  var element = employee["Employee_Names"][i];

  // We push only name
  allNames.push( element.Name );
  
  // We push full json object
   //allNames.push( element );
}

// Now we assign new json key with our names
employee = Object.assign(employee, { "NEW_NAMES" : allNames });

// Our new employee json
console.log(employee);
```